# Multiple >> redirects to same file by 2 scripts, mid-sentence breaking

Tags: linux, files, cron, io-redirection

I have 2 programs, both writing to the same file (`/tmp/outfile`). Started by cron at the same time.

Basically this is what is happening:

```
echo -n "1111111111" >> /tmp/outfile
```

And at the same time:

```
echo -n "2222222222" >> /tmp/outfile
```

The output file says "`11111222222222211111`". This is an example, I am talking about hundreds  of lines, where one line is "cut" mid-sentence, but simply put, above thing is happening.

How to prevent this behavior?

Comment: Well, you have different threads with a handle on the same file, the behavior that you're seeing is perfectly logical. To prevent it, the different cron jobs that you have should each lock a file when they're writing to it, unlock it when they're done, and wait before writing to a file when it is locked. Have a look at `flock` -- it provides the necessary mechanisms to do so.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/299627/multiple-appenders-writing-to-the-same-file-on-nfs-share/299653#299653

Comment: Prevent it and do what?

Comment: Flock sounds like an answer. I want to prevent sentences from being "broken" in 2 parts :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two immediately obvious ways to solve this:

1. Serialize the tasks. Instead of scheduling the two tasks at the same time, schedule a script that runs the tasks one after the other.
2. Use a advisory locking scheme to lock the writing operation of the tasks in such a way that only one task can write at a time.  See questions tagged with [lock](/questions/tagged/lock) and [flock](/questions/tagged/flock).

These two may be combined into a single script that runs both tasks in the background while the tasks themselves uses some form of locking as to not produce garbled/intermingled output.