# Accessing NFS export locally: data consistency?

Tags: nfs, fanotify

System I know has /etc/exports (redacted address range; NFSv4, Linux 5.8.3):

```
/usr/users  192.168.68.0/255.255.255.128(rw,root_squash,sync,no_subtree_check)
```

which is mounted on client machines (to offer remote home directories). But on the same server that exports these, users are allowed to log in locally and access their local home directory directly via /usr/users; which is its own ext3 filesystem (mount options are only `rw,relatime`).

Doesn't that mean the NFS server can not know when a user modifies a file locally, so that remote and local files diverge? Or is consistency guaranteed by some `fanotify`-based mechanism or similar?

So, to conclude:

- I want to know how mixed local/NFS access makes different guarantees than NFS-only access

  - especially w.r.t. server-side and client-side caching
  - especially w.r.t. whether we can tell at which point an NFS read would be consistent after a local write, and vice versa
- I want to know whether a file being changed locally gets propagated at all to the clients (for data consistency, but also for `select`/`poll` reasons)

  - especially w.r.t. how that is done/implemented and what requirements on the local file system/access need to be fulfilled

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140949/discussion-on-question-by-marcus-muller-accessing-nfs-export-locally-data-consi).

Comment: NFS writes are already not atomic meaning [multiple NFS clients can have divergent copies of files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/299653/20140).  Transitively we can infer that NFS clients can diverge from the "local" file on the NFS server... If two different clients have different copies of the same file then at least one of them is divergent from the server's copy.  Could you clarify... are you asking if the effect is different when combining local and NFS writes, vs combining two different NFS client writes?

Comment: @PhilipCouling exactly, that. I wasn't even aware of the append/seek problem! Let me just add a sentence to the end of the question